# package ssl cert, private key, and intermediate certs into single pfx?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I have this kit of files:

- 1.crt: My certificate
- 2.key: private key
- 3.crt: intermediate cert auth (from godaddy)
- 4.crt: root cert or intermediate cert (from godaddy) n.crt: some others like this from godaddy

How do I package all of these into a single pfx for a web server app?

(this needs to be portable , in one file, for deploy purposes)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make a chain.pem file by appending PEM formated 1.crt, 3.crt and 4.crt.

Then run this command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey 2.key  -in chain.pem -name some_name -out final_result.p12
```

You will be asked to define an encryption password for the archive (it is mandatory to be able to import the file in IIS). You may also be asked for the private key password if there is one!

More info [here](https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/288.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618108/adding-an-intermediate-certificates-to-a-pkcs12-file)