# CA Cert Install Process for Tomcat 7

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl

I have gotten 4 certs (1 root, 2 intermediate, and 1 domain to be deployed in that order) from my CA and I am curious about what the process is for getting the chain imported into a keystore correctly. I was able to get the domain cert installed and desktops/laptops can connect securely but not mobile (I get the red x and the crossed out https in mobile Chrome). Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862908/ssl-certificate-is-not-trusted-on-mobile-only), it appears that my chain is somehow messed up. This is the first time I have done this, so I tried using the keytool tutorials that had me create a self signed cert and then add the CA certs to the keystore, but that didn't work so I resorted to using [this article](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/06/13/how-to-keystore-creating-jks-file-from-existing-private-key-and-certificate/) that uses openssl to import just the domain cert and then convert the p12 to a jks. This article is what got me to the point where I could connect from non-mobile devices securely. But I am still stuck in non-secured on mobile. My CA is Comodo and the link I am using is [here](https://www.sooperdaive.com/LeiaDemo/LeiaLoginServlet). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like everything is working now. I used the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618108/adding-an-intermediate-certificates-to-a-pkcs12-file). It's weird and kind of wonky to have to manually paste in cert info, but it worked! If anyone else has a better process I'd love to hear it though.