# code signing error with install4j

Tags: install4j

When I try to sign my exe using a p12 keystore I get the following error:

> codesigning.p12 does not contain the complete certificate chain

However, I can sign it without problem using the windows signTool.exe by executing:

> signtool sign /f codesigning.p12 /p $keyStorePassword myprogram.exe

Any ideas how to get this working in install4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

signtool can access intermediate certificates in the Windows keystore, something that install4j does not do.

Other than creating a self-contained certificate (see [Adding an intermediate certificates to a pkcs12 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618108/adding-an-intermediate-certificates-to-a-pkcs12-file)), you can use the "Executable processing" step of the media wizard and call

```
C:\Path\To\signtool sign /f codesigning.p12 /p $keyStorePassword $EXECUTABLE
```

to perform external signing of all executables.