# Signing executables with EV-Certificate with Install4J

Tags: java, code-signing, install4j, signtool

our company ordered an EV-Certificate from [GlobalSign](https://www.globalsign.com/en/code-signing-certificate/ev-code-signing-certificates/).

Before we had a normal code signing certificate as a p12 file which we could use in Install4J.

Now, with the new certificate we have no cert-files but a usb-token.

Is there a built-in way to use the usb-token to sign executables/jars? Or do I need to use the "Executable processing" step of media wizard like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025805/code-signing-error-with-install4j)?

Maybe a way to sign all installers (win, mac, linux) from one machine (like macos)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Ingo's answer, it's not possible to use an EV Code Sign certificate. I hope, in future, it will.

As I said in my question, you have to use "Executable processing" in media wizard (for windows only).

You can use microsoft's codesign on windows itself or you can you a little tool called [jsign](https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/) which you can use on all platforms to sign windows executables with EV Code Sign certificate.

This is our call to jsign:

java -jar jsign-2.0.jar --keystore ./eToken.cfg --alias %[GetAliasOfYourToken](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1702232)% --storetype PKCS11 --tsaurl http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode --storepass %WriteTokenPasswordHere% $EXECUTABLE

eToken.cfg is a simple text-file with two lines:

name=eToken

library=/usr/local/lib/libeTPkcs11.dylib (because I'm on MacOS)

for Windows it should be:

library=c:\WINDOWS\system32\eTPKCS11.dll

Comment: The windows equalivent fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Or do I need to use the "Executable processing" step of media wizard like 
>   mentioned here?

Yes, that's the only way.

> Maybe a way to sign all installers (win, mac, linux) from one machine (like macos)?

Unfortunately, that's not possible.

---

**Update 2019-10-22**

Since install4j 8.0, hardware security modules (PKCS#11) are supported for Windows code signing and can be configured on the General Settings->Code Signing step.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Are there any plans to implement the feature to sign installer using a hardware token?

Comment: No, I don't think that it would be feasible to implement this as a multi-platform feature

Comment: What does Install4J do/use for signing executables/dmgs? Is it a completely own implementation or does it use an third party implementation?

Comment: It's implemented from scratch in Java code, no external tools are used.