# Secure handshake failing during IBM.MQ MQQueueManager on Linux .net core

Tags: c#, linux, openssl, ibm-mq, .net-standard-2.0

We are trying to connect to IBM MQ from RHEL 8.3 using .net core 3.1 application.
The same code runs ok on Windows- we are able to connect to QM.
We are facing an error that comes, as we believe, from openssl:

> ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: **SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
> ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 >alert bad certificate**
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, Byte[] recvBuf, Int32 recvOffset, Int32 >recvCount, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount) in >/_/src/Common/src/Interop/Unix/System.Security.Cryptography.Native/Interop.OpenSsl.cs:line 278

We can see that MQClient loaded certificates

> 00000157 12:30:07.116059   536167.15  -----------{
> MQEncryptedSocket.MakeSecuredConnection()
> 00000158 12:30:07.116425   536167.15   Created an instance of
> SSLStreams
> 00000159 12:30:07.116466   536167.15   Setting current certificate
> store as 'User'
> 0000015A 12:30:07.116528   536167.15   Linux so use My & CurrentUser
> 0000015B 12:30:07.116542   536167.15   Created store object to access
> certificates
> 0000015C 12:30:07.116780   536167.15   Opened store
> 0000015D 12:30:07.116795   536167.15   Accessing certificate - ZZZZ
> 0000015E 12:30:07.230836   536167.15   Number of certificates in the
> store:5
> 0000015F 12:30:07.231092   536167.15   TLS12 supported - True
> 00000160 12:30:07.233622   536167.15   Setting SslProtol as Tls12
> 00000161 12:30:07.233652   536167.15   Starting SSL Authentication

We have unit test that verifies if cert of given subject exists in that store and it passes.
What we've done already:

1. We build openssl 1.1.1h and linked it system wide.
2. We verified cert store. The cert we are using is valid

```cs
    var cert = x509Store2.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, mockIbmMqOptions.MqCertificateLabel, true).Count;
    x509Store2.Close();
    x509Store2.Dispose();
    Assert.True(cert > 0);
```

3. We ran the code on Windows with success.
4. We searched for sslv3 alert bad certificate in openssl source and found nothing but statics with error code 1420 but not referenced.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you specifying the TLS version in you c# code?  When you do not specify the TLS version in client a default version is used which may bed different on different machines.  Also the certificate has to be loaded on both client and server.  When a TLS connection is started the server sends a list of Certificate names to the client and then the client looks up the names in the Certificate Stores.  The certifcate encryption mode must be compatible with the version of TLS.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: Yes we are:   ```00000154 12:30:07.110057   536167.15   CipherSpec value is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256```

Comment: Looks like your client is requesting TLS 1.2.  and server is not accepting the certificate.  See : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_ssl_security.htm

Comment: How can I check it? It works ok from Windows. I wonder if there is something that could help to trace the issue.

Comment: Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler you can see the TLS messages include the certificate block with the list of certificates.  But that is working on Windows.  Something is failing on the lookup in certificate stores a IBM MQ machine.  See following : https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-mq-personal-and-ca-certificates-explained-and-how-identify-them

Comment: You can review the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` at the time you get the error for more details on what the QM is seeing.

Comment: Also what is the label on the cert (friendly name)?  By default with a MQ client app it will look for a cert with the label `ibmwebspheremq<username_in_lowercase>`, so if your process ran as a user named `tomash`, then by default MQ will look for a cert labeled as `ibmwebspheremqtomash`, you can override this default and specify a specific label.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on AMQERR. I will have to ask 3rd party to send it to me.  As for friendlyname- as you know, the client is written in .net core using ibm mq .net standard library as client. When we import pfx to .net core key store in RHEL the friendly name is empty and on Windows key store is set to ZZZZ and CertificateLabel is set to ZZZZ.

Comment: Do you mean you are setting the cert label to match the name in the .net core key store?  This other recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580857/unable-to-autheticate-to-ibm-mq-c-sharp-with-tls-certificate) may be helpful.

Comment: Yes, we set CertificateLabel to match FriendlyName.

Comment: check that question, the guy said he had to only import the single cert not all the signers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @JoshMc based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580857/unable-to-autheticate-to-ibm-mq-c-sharp-with-tls-certificate?noredirect=1&lq=1) we successfully managed to finish the handshake.
I think this is a general solution for .net core on RHEL and IBM MQ Client libraries:

1. Be sure that CA and Intermediate CA are stored in /usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/anchors/ or /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
2. If your pfx contain certificates in certification path **EXPORT ONLY private key and public cert**
3. Be sure to have Friendly Name set to some value.
4. Add exported pfx to .net core key store `certificate-tool add`

5. Set CertificateLabel to match FriendlyName or set the friendly name to ibmwebspheremq<username_in_lowercase>

Comment: You can also set the friendly name to `ibmwebspheremq<username_in_lowercase>` and skip setting the CertificateLabel to match.

Comment: 20 hrs to go :)