How do I set up an SSL connection to an IBM MQ using IBMXMSDotnet on .NET 8 on a Linux system?
please bear with me as this is my first post on here.
I am trying to write a .NET 8 client application that connects to an IBM MQ QueueManager that makes use of TLS. Here is a snippet of the code that I am currently using to set up the connection.
    var props = new Hashtable
    {
        { MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, _host },
        { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, _channel },
        { MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, _port }
    };

    if (_sslEnabled)
    {
        props.Add(MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, _friendlyName);
        props.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, _cipherSpec);
        props.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "*USER");
    }

    using var manager = new MQQueueManager("qm1", props);
    using var queue = manager.AccessQueue("test_queue", MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT);

This code works without any issues on a Windows OS. The CertLabel that I provide is the friendly name of a cert that I have installed in my current user repository.
The issue comes in now where I am trying to make use of the same code on a Linux OS. Linux does not seem to support the friendly name field for certificates, so I am wondering how I could possibly set up a secure connection via code to my IBM MQ on Linux specifically.
I am making use of the nuget package IBMXMSDotnetClient v. 9.3.5.
I am happy to provide any additional information as far as possible.
I have tried to make use of the following and received MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE

Set MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY to the cert thumbprint
Set MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY to ibmmqwebsphere<user> (where <user> is the current user trying to run the application)
Set MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY to ibmmqwebspheremq<user> (where <user> is the current user trying to run the application or the user id of the user that created the cert)

I have also tried the following, but received MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR

Set MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY to the cert subject distinguished name, which is "CN=XXX, OU=XXX, O=XXX, L=XXX, S=XXX, C=XXX"
Set MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY to just a part of the subject distinguished name: "CN=XXX"

I have also noted, that if my IBM cert is the only cert installed on the linux OS, then it resolves the correct certificate regardless of what value is set as the CertLabelProperty. That is only if it is the only cert available, if another cert is installed then it the handshake fails when trying to connect

This answer may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64911987/secure-handshake-failing-during-ibm-mq-mqqueuemanager-on-linux-net-core the label in the pkcs12 is equivalent to the friendly name on windows.

@JoshMc, thanks for your response. I took a look at the answer of the link that you provided. I saw that the intermediate certificate was not installed in the trust store. I have since installed it, but I am still receiving an MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR when trying to connect. I have swapped out setting the cert label for SSL peer name.


if my IBM cert is the only cert installed on the linux OS, then it
resolves the correct certificate

This implies that when you have other certificates in the store then the wrong certificate is being used.
From the documentation

For client certificates, the IBM® MQ managed .NET client accesses the
Windows keystore and loads all of the client's certificates that are
matched either by certificate label or matched by the string.
When selecting a certificate to use, the IBM MQ managed .NET client
always uses the first matching certificate for the SSLStream TLS
handshake.
If you set the certificate label, the IBM MQ managed .NET client
searches the Windows certificate store with the given label name to
identify the client certificate. It loads all matching certificates
and uses the first certificate on the list.

IE. The other certificate also matches the label _friendlyName. What is _friendlyName set to? Is it set to anything? Might be worthwhile debugging the code to see what label you are using in the code.
If that doesn't work then going back to the documentation

If certificate label is not set, then the certificate that matches the
string "ibmwebspheremq" and the current logged on user (in lowercase)
is searched for and used.

IE. Drop the
props.Add(MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, _friendlyName);

and ensure the MQ certificate has the name ibmwebspheremq.

Thanks for your response. I am having an issue with this process on Linux, where friendly name is not supported by the keystore. _friendlyName is the variable holding the value of the label, and on Windows, we set the friendly name equal to the label value. I will try your suggestion though, thanks again
