# Azure Function IBM MQ Setup with pfx Certificate

Tags: azure, azure-functions, ibm-mq, azure-function-app, xms

I am having a connection problem when I am trying to set up a connection to a IBM MQ V6 QueueManager and a .net client using IBM.XMS namespace in **Azure Function**.

I am setting up the connection like this:

```
XMSFactoryFactory xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
IConnectionFactory cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "servername.ibmcloud.com");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1415);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "SYSTEM.SSL.SVRCONN");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);  //Managed Client
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "OM_QMGR");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V1);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, "servername.ibmcloud.com(1415)");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CLIENT_CERT_LABEL, "ibmwebspheremqsystem");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "*SYSTEM");

return cf.CreateConnection();
```

This works properly when I run it in my local machine where pfx certificate is installed in my MMC console.
Om my local system it is working properly, as it is able to find the WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY from "System".

I have added the pfx certificate in Azure Function under "Private Key Certificates", and it appears as healthy, just like this Image [image: Azure Function Private Key Certificates]

but when I call the cf.CreateConnection I get an error 2538: MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE as an exception.
I know the issue is because of WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY property, I am not sure what to provide in place of "*SYSTEM" so that this works properly on Azure Function.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.
Thank you all.

Comment: Have you tried `*USER` in place of `*SYSTEM`?

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580857/unable-to-autheticate-to-ibm-mq-c-sharp-with-tls-certificate

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc for your comment, it worked. Thank you for your edit too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was solved in the comments by JoshMc.

The above code works with Azure Function with just one modification.
Put `*USER` as the value of `XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY` instead of `*SYSTEM` and this should work on Azure Function.