# Error MQException caught: 2059 - MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE .Net Core Linux Docker Container IBM MQ, caused by cipherspec mismatch

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, ibm-mq

I have a .net core managed client running in a Linux docker container. I am trying to connect to the IBM message queue using SSL and it connects successfully using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256. I tested again by asking them to change the server to AES_256. However, when they switch to AES_256 i.e I try the same on **TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256** I get 2059 - MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE.

In windows, you can specify default the cipher spec by going to group policy editor.
example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/manage-tls
My question is how do I do that in the docker container. My image used is from Microsoft dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim
Here is my code for reference,

```
 private static string _host = "GH2134";
        private static int _port = 1414;
        private static string _channel= "AES256.TEST.CHANNEL";
        private static string _qmgr= "MQMGR";
        private static string _cipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";
        private static string _mqUser = "mymqUser";
        private static string _mqPassword = "mymqPassword@";   
        private static string _keyRepository = "*USER";
              
        var properties = new Hashtable();
        properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
        properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, _host);
        properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, _port);
        properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, _channel);
        properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, _mqUser);
        properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, _mqPassword);
        properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY,_cipherSpec);         
        properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, _keyRepository);
          
        var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(_qmgr, properties);
        Console.Write("Connection created successfully...\n\n");
```

I checked the bash for installed root@097aa5a44f52:/app# ssl cyphers -v
Didn't find it **TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256** how did I add it, like in windows group policy editor

```
root@097aa5a44f52:/app# openssl ciphers -v
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
AES128-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384   TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256   TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
```

Update:
I verified with downgrading the nuget version of IBM® Message Service Client for .NET Standard (XMS .NET) 9.2.2 to 9.1.4
I was surprised to know that I get the 2059 error also with TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 so I am might also guess that this could be a bug in the IBM's client library?

Comment: AES256-SHA256 = TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://serverfault.com/questions/1033439/how-do-i-disable-just-one-cipher-out-of-openssl-tlsv1-3-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer my own question. I did the tests with older library version of IBMXMS
nuget packages. It did not support AES 128 as well, There is currently a bug in the official IBMXMS .net library that it does not support CYPHERSPECS TLS_RSA_AES_**256**_WITH_RSA_SHA256 in the latest one. It supports AES128

> However this is the case only in the **Linux** environment. In windows AES 256 works, provided that its also  changed to the same spec in group policy. Here is a link on how to it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/manage-tls

Hence if you are using IBMs .Net Client Core in Linux, then only upto TLS_RSA_AES_**128**_WITH_RSA_SHA256 unless IBM releases a new library dll or a nuget package that supports it. As of now the version I am using is
from nuget,  IBMXMSDotnetClient Version="9.2.2"
in Openssl, there is already support

Comment: What version is the queue manager you connect to?

Comment: Hi @JoshMc its IBM version is 8.0.0.16, its older version because the Biztalk 2013 has support only upto that version.